# Auto height a div between two other divs

Tags: html, css

I am going to make a sidebar like Google+ or Facebook sidebar.

sidebar is `position:fixed; left:0; top:0; bottom:0; width: 250px` and has:

A header with 50px height
A footer with 50px height.
A content with dynamic height based on browser height.

[image]

any help?

Comment: I think you need CSS tables.

Comment: @bjb568 Not necessarily ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply position the body of the sidebar absolutely within its containing parent. Since the header and footer are sticky (I presume) and are of fixed height, you can use:

```
#sidebar-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 50px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    /* or width: 100%; if you don't want to use the left/right positions */
}
```

You can see a proof-of-concept fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/2r4r6/

**Edit:** If you're feeling adventurous, you can set the sidebar content height using `calc(100vh - 100px);`, but [older browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=vh) as well as [iOS Safari](http://thatemil.com/blog/2013/06/13/viewport-relative-unit-strangeness-in-ios-6/) has problems computing `vh` properly ;)

Comment: and if I want to scroll the content. what should i set for max-height  or height ?

Comment: vmin seems to work better than vh, and it's almost always the same.

Comment: @bjb568 Not necessarily. `vmin` takes the smaller of viewport height or width. If your viewport orientation changes, that will mess up the height calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Specify height:100% ; or give height:auto;

Hope it helps you..

Comment: It needs to allow the header and footer to be visible.